# Appending 2 dimensional list (dense output of tfidf result) into pandas dataframe rows, each index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have the below output after tfidf vectorizer. I want to parse dense output into a pandas dataframe column but I couldn't directly apply toarray or todense function to sparse tfidf output and pass it to pandas dataframe column. So I received the dense output of tfidf results into a list. Now the list is of shape (6,20) and I want to parse each row of list iteratively into  rows in a pandas dataframe column as length of dataframe column is also 6. I tried converting list into pandas series and pass it to dataframe but didn't work on 2 dimensional list.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

new_docs = ['Men Tops Tshirts missing ', 'Electronics Computers   Tablets Components Parts Razer',
           'Women Tops   Blouses Blouse Target ', 'Home Home Décor Home Décor Accents missing ', 
           'Women Jewelry Necklaces missing  ', 'Women Other Other missing  ']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),
               min_df=3, max_df=0.9, strip_accents='unicode', use_idf=1,
               smooth_idf=1, sublinear_tf=1 ))
new_term_freq_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(new_docs)
print (vectorizer.vocabulary_)
print (new_term_freq_matrix.todense())

example = pd.DataFrame({'test_data_column': new_docs})
lt_1 = []
lt_1 = (vectorizer.fit_transform(new_docs)).toarray()

print(lt_1)
```

[image: output of lt_1]

```
print(lt_1.shape)
(6, 20)
print(example)
                              test_data_column
0  Men Tops Tshirts missing                              
1  Electronics Computers   Tablets Components Parts Razer
2  Women Tops   Blouses Blouse Target                    
3  Home Home Décor Home Décor Accents missing            
4  Women Jewelry Necklaces missing                       
5  Women Other Other missing
```

Comment: Hi yes. I just accepted it. My apologies. I was experimenting.

Comment: No worries, thanks again, and good luck with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the `DataFrame` in one fell swoop, passing `new_docs` as the index and `new_term_freq_matrix`, the TFIDF values, as your data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(new_term_freq_matrix.todense(), index=new_docs)
```

If you don't want to have `new_docs` as the index, then, create the dataframe and insert `new_docs` in later -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(new_term_freq_matrix.todense())
df.insert(0, 'docs', new_docs)
```

Alternatively,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(new_term_freq_matrix.todense(), index=new_docs).reset_index()
```

The former is more performant, because `reset_index` returns a copy of your entire data.

One more aside, if you're dealing with sparse data, you might be interested in the [`pd.SparseDataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#sparse-data-structures) API.

Comment: Hi, I was just wondering, what difference would it make if we are having a row of data with the entire array: [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.55204307  0.40967959  0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.47186812  0.55204307  0.        ] to what difference it would make if we are having each value in separate columns in further calculations, say a logistic regression.  Are my thoughts on this right? would there be a difference?

Comment: @RajeshThevar I think it is easier for scikit learn to understand a DataFrame of scalars instead of a column of lists. Also, pre-processing scalars is more efficient than column of lists. But in the end it depends.